# ORA-03106: fatal two-task communication protocol error in batch update

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

I have a merge query, where one of the column is of type CLOB

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("MERGE..");    
for(List) {
//Update part
...
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream2 = new ByteArrayInputStream(model.getDescription().getBytes());
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader2 = new InputStreamReader(inputStream2);
pstmt.setClob(i++, inputStreamReader2); 
//Insert
..
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(model.getDescription().getBytes());
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
pstmt.setClob(i++, inputStreamReader);  

pstmt.addbatch() 
}
pstmt.executeBatch();
```

it gives me `java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-03106: fatal two-task communication protocol` error at executeBatch line, but when I just set pstmt.setString(i++, "") it works, meaning this exception because of these 2 CLOB setting. What mistake am I making?

Comment: Which version of the Oracle JDBC driver are you using, and which Oracle server version (full version numbers for both please)

Comment: Oracle JDBC Driver version 11.1.0.7.0,  ojdbc6.jar

Comment: And your Oracle version?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using clob = conn.createClob(); Not sure why i did not use this before.